Add to cart multiple variations via JQuery and Ajax in WooCommerce
I'm using add_to_cart method to add a variation to cart with Ajax, this works but I can't find a way to add multiple variations using the same request.
If I send one_data it works, but not with multi_data
product_id in this code works if the product is variable, so it's the variation id.
Code:
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document.body).on('click', '#button', function(e) {
        //const one_data = { product_id: 592, quantity: 1 }
        const multi_data = [
            { product_id: 592, quantity: 2 },
            { product_id: 593, quantity: 1 },
            { product_id: 594, quantity: 3 }
        ];

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart' ),
            data: multi_data,
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            },
        });
    });
});


To add multiple variations to the cart via jQuery and Ajax in WooCommerce, you need to send individual requests for each variation or create a custom endpoint to handle multiple items in a single request. WooCommerce’s built-in Ajax handler for adding to the cart (add_to_cart) doesn’t support adding multiple items in one request out of the box.

I guess you're right, thank you for showing me the way!

This requires to build a complete custom Ajax Multi Add to Cart functionality.
In the code below, the products details to be added to cart at once, are located in the first PHP function. You can always add IF/ELSE statements to add conditions with different products.
It works directly with variation Ids (from variable products) and also with simple products.
The PHP code:
// Define below all the products to be added to cart
add_filter('wc_multi_add_to_cart_products_data', 'define_products_data_to_be_added', 10, 1 );
function define_products_data_to_be_added( $products_data ) {
    // Here, define the Products Ids (or Variation Ids) and the quantities (optional)
    $products_data = array(
        [ 'id' => 98,  'qty' => 1 ],
        [ 'id' => 99,  'qty' => 2 ],
        [ 'id' => 100, 'qty' => 1 ],
    );

    return $products_data;
}

// Enqueuing scripts
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_multi_add_to_cart_scripts');
function enqueue_multi_add_to_cart_scripts() {
    // Custom filter hook
    $products_data = apply_filters('wc_multi_add_to_cart_products_data', array() );

    if ( $products_data ) {
        // With the main theme use: get_template_directory_uri() . /js/…
        // With a child theme use: get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . /js/…
        // With a plugin use: plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . js/…
        wp_enqueue_script('multi-add-to-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/multi-add-to-cart.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        
        wp_localize_script('multi-add-to-cart', 'wc_multi_atc', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
            'action'   => 'multi_add_to_cart',
            'products' => $products_data, 
            'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('multi_atc'),
        ));
    }

    
}

// Handle Ajax Request
add_action('wp_ajax_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_add_to_cart');
function multi_add_to_cart() {
    if ( isset($_POST['nonce']) 
    && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'multi_atc')
    && isset($_POST['products']) && is_array($_POST['products']) ) {
        $response  = array();


        foreach( wc_clean($_POST['products']) as $values ) {
            if ( isset($values['id']) && $values['id'] > 0 
            && isset($values['qty']) && $values['qty'] > 0 ) {
                $product_id   = absint($values['id']);
                $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );

                $not_added    = array( 
                    'key'   => null,
                    'added' => 0,
                    'id'    => $product_id,
                );

                if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
                    $response[] = $not_added;
                    continue;
                }

                $quantity     = wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $values['qty'] ) );
                $variation_id = 0;
                $variation    = array();

                if ( $product && 'variation' === $product->get_type() ) {
                    $variation_id = $product_id;
                    $product_id   = $product->get_parent_id();
                    $variation    = $product->get_variation_attributes(); 
                }
                
                if ( 'publish' !== get_post_status( $product_id ) ) {
                    $response[] = $not_added;
                    continue;
                }
                
                if ( $variation_id && 'publish' !== $product->get_status() ) {
                    $response[] = $not_added;
                    continue;
                }

                $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
                
                $response[] = array( 
                    'key'   => $cart_item_key,
                    'added' => $cart_item_key ? $quantity : '0',
                    'id'    => $variation_id ?: $product_id,
                );
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty($response) ) {
            wp_send_json($response);
        }
    }
    wp_die('Something went wrong.');
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
The JavaScript code in a file named "multi-add-to-cart.js" located in a "js" subfolder:
jQuery( function($) {
  
    // wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue
    if ( typeof wc_multi_atc === 'undefined' ) {
        console.log('Error: "wc_multi_atc" not defined.');
        return false;
    }

    $(document.body).on('click', '#button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_multi_atc.ajax_url,
            data: data = {
                'action': wc_multi_atc.action,
                'nonce': wc_multi_atc.nonce,
                'products': wc_multi_atc.products
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});

The HTML for the Multi add to cart button (example):
<div id="button" class="button">Add Products to Cart</div>

Tested and works.

Related:

Add to cart a product variation via JQuery and Ajax in WooCommerce
WooCommerce Adding multiple items to the cart with Ajax

